# While using the camera or gallery in app, it crashes on backButton press

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use the camera or gallery (as an alert) in an application for uploading documents. The app crashes if the back button is pressed and no image was selected.

```
  private fun getImageFromCamera() {
    val takePicture = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePicture.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKE_PICTURE)
    }
  }

private fun getImageFromGallery() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select 
                                                  Picture"), PICK_IMAGE)
    }
}
```

There is no issue regarding the permission for the camera. I didn't post all the code.

**onActivityResult:**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                val inputStream1 = contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream1)
                mUploadPanCardImageButton!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                mUploadPanCardTextView?.visibility = View.GONE
            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }else if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val extras1 = data.extras
            bitmap = extras1!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            mUploadPanCardImageButton!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            mUploadPanCardTextView?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception that I am getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=12345, result=0, data=null} to activity {in.inspiringwave.firstapp/in.inspiringwave.firstapp.UploadDocsActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data at
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4173) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4216) at
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
```

Comment: shouldn't be `data:Intent?` because then you would've to check for nullability of `data`

Answer (score 1):

Make your onActivityResult Nullable by putting ? for intent like this-

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
```

Comment: Thanks A lot sir.You Solved My Issue in seconds.so GreatFul to you

Comment: Note that '?' doesn't make the intent null safe. On the contrary: It is now nullable.